# linq query to group the items

Tags: linq, linq-group

```
var sales = _salesService.GetSales(parameters)
```

The list is something like

```
var listSales = new List<SalesData>();
listSales .Add(new SalesData
{
    Name = "Apple",
    Quantity = 1000
});
listSales .Add(new SalesData
{
    Name = "Banana",
    Quantity = 2000
});
listSales .Add(new SalesData
{
    Name = "Peach",
    Quantity = 1
});
listSales .Add(new SalesData
{
    Name = "Mango",
    Quantity = 1
});
```

I want to write a linq query so that I can group the 'Name' as 'Others' if the quantity is less than 1 percent of the total quantity.

So result of the query should be something like

```
Apple  56
Banana 23
Others 2  -- ( peach's quantity less than than 1% + Mango Quantity less than 1%)
```

Comment: Will there ever be two entries with the same name in the original data, e.g. two for Banana?

Comment: Also, your example doesn't work - because you've got a total quantity of 81 items, so both Mango and Peach are above 1% of that quantity...

Comment: please ignore the figures..applogies for that...The names will be unique in the list thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it sounds like first you need to know the total quantity. That's easy enough:

```
var total = listSales.Sum(entry => entry.Quantity);
```

Then you need to work out the cutoff point, which is 1% of it:

```
var cutoff = total / 100;
```

For the grouping and summing, I'd probably go in three steps:

- Transform the original list into a sequence with entries of "Others"
- Group entries by name
- Sum per group

So the overall code would be:

```
var total = listSales.Sum(entry => entry.Quantity);
// TODO: Work out whether you want the cutoff to be exclusive or not.
var cutoff = total / 100;
var results = listSales.Select(entry => entry.Quantity >= cutoff ?
                                            entry :
                                            new SalesData { 
                                                Name = "Others",
                                                Quantity = entry.Quantity
                                            })
                       .GroupBy(entry => entry.Name, entry => entry.Quantity)
                       .Select(group => new { Name = group.Key,
                                              Total = group.Sum() });
```

You *can* combine the "group and select" operations, but personally I find the above simpler to read.

Comment: thanks..any tips for improving my linq?? I am new to it.

Comment: @freeCoder52511: It's mostly practice, in my experience. It definitely gets easier over time. It's also worth becoming familiar with both "lambda syntax" (as here) and query expressions.

Comment: Hi jon..what if I Want to select one more additional row. for eg select name, total and Trade. thanks

Comment: @freeCoder52511: Well where would the trade come from? You're grouping by name, so there could be multiple values with different trades within the same group. If you want to group by name *and* trade, use an anonymous type - `GroupBy(entry => new { entry.Name, entry.Trade }`

Comment: great! sorry thats what I meant..wanted to group by name and trade.